# When Uploading Image from Google Cloud to FabricJS Canvas- Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, fabricjs

How can I resolve the "SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement'" issue in Fabric.js when loading images from Google Cloud Storage onto a canvas? Additionally, how do I address CORS errors such as "no 'access-control-allow-origin' header"?

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(
    {your image url from Google Cloud Storage},
    function (img) {
        // Adjust scaling as needed
        img.scaleToWidth(fc.current.width);
        img.scaleToHeight(fc.current.height);
        canvas.setBackgroundImage(
            img,
            canvas.renderAll.bind(fc.current),
            {
                originX: "left",
                originY: "top",
            }
        );
    }.bind(this),
    {
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    }
);
```